# Applying Only One Plain 301 Redirect Out of a Series

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having an issue where plain 301 redirects are acting kind of strange. It seems that the multiple redirects are applied to one request. Here's an example.

```
(1) Redirect 301 /brands http://www.example.com/designer
(2) Redirect 301 /brands/Adidas.html http://www.example.com/designer
```

`www.example.com/brands` directs as I intended to `http://www.example.com/designer`.
`www.example.com/brands/Adidas.html` directs to `http://www.example.com/designer/Adidas.html`. If I remove `(1)` entirely, `(2)` works.

How do I make each redirect apply one and only for the exact match?

Comment: `Redirect` directive is provided by [`mod_alias`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirect). You do not need `RewriteEngine On` for this.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue, is it? I've updated my question.